# Simple encryption program

Tags: python, arrays, encryption

I'm having some problems writing a simple encryption/decryption program in python, simply involving replacing the elements of one array with another. I have two arrays, the array that needs to be encrypted and the key where the first element is equivalent to a and the last to z.

I'm assuming I will need to make all instances of a in the first array = key[0], and so on, but I don't know how to go about writing some code. Some hints or guidance would be much appreciated.

Note that I can't import any libraries, and I have not been taught dictionaries.

Follow up question, but related question. How would I replace all elements of the same value in a list. i.e. How would I replace all of the 'a' values in the text list with the first value of the key list?

```
for c in text:        
    if c == 'a':
        c = key[0]
```

Gives me an error: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track for implementing a simple substitution cipher. What have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck? Here's one tip that might make it simpler: Consider making the key a dict, so that when you see the letter a in the plaintext, you can just check key['a'] to see what letter to replace it with.

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn it into a dictionary, I haven't been taught how to yet. Honestly, I haven't gotten anything down yet as I can't think of a way to actually write the code. I have the basic idea of how each component will work, but I can't put it together.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment, please add the homework tag if it is

Comment: The error means that key is not a list, it is a function, can you show the definition?

Comment: `string.maketrans()` and `string.translate()` are functions specifically designed for doing one-to-one character replacements.

Comment: Ugh, that's an embarrassing mistake. It turns out they are of type 'numpy.ndarray'. It came with preset functions already defined, so that's where I stuffed up. With this knowledge does solving the problem become any easier?

Comment: please give the definitions of text and key, without them it's rather difficult to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

first convert key into a dict, then you can use a simple list substitution

```
key = {chr(ord('a')+i): e for i, e in enumerate(key)}
encrypted = [key[e] for e in unencrypted]
```

alteratively

```
encrypted = [key[ord(e) - ord('a')] for e in unencrypted]
```

Comment: Haven't been taught dictionaries yet, I think it is meant to be completed using lists/arrays.

Everything I try is giving me "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable"

I've updated my question a bit if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way would be:

```
def encrypt(iterable,encryption_dictionary):
    itertype = type(iterable)
    return itertype(''.join((encryption_dictionary[i] for i in iterable)))
```

To create the encryption_dictionary, you can use

```
{key1:mappedvalue1,key2:mappedvalue2}
```

and so on with : indicating pairs and "," breaking between pairs.